# PHP - Strange Session bug

Tags: php, session

i'm using an extern API via SOAP in PHP. The normal workflow of this API is:

- authenticate();
- search whatever you want
- session_close();

Following this procedure as told in the manual my little SOAP Client does this:

```
$auth_url  = "http://search.isiknowledge.com/esti/wokmws/ws/WOKMWSAuthenticate?wsdl";
$auth_client = @new SoapClient($auth_url,$Options);
$auth_response = $auth_client->authenticate();

$search_url = "http://search.isiknowledge.com/esti/wokmws/ws/WokSearchLite?wsdl";
$search_client = @new SoapClient($search_url,$Options);
$search_client->__setCookie('SID',$auth_response->return);

$search_array = array(
  'queryParameters' => array(
    'databaseID' => 'WOS',
    'userQuery' => 'TS=Medical Informatics',
    'editions' => array(
      array('collection' => 'WOS', 'edition' => 'SSCI'),
      array('collection' => 'WOS', 'edition' => 'SCI')
    ),
    'queryLanguage' => 'en'
  ),
  'retrieveParameters' => array(
    'count' => '99',
    'fields' => array(
      array('name' => 'Date', 'sort' => 'D')
    ),
    'firstRecord' => '1'
  )
);

try{
  $search_response = $search_client->search($search_array);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

var_dump($search_response);

$auth_client->closeSession();
```

Now for the strange behaviour:

As i load this little PHP-Script it sometimes works and sometimes does not. When it works it outputs correctly the found data and when it doesnt i get something like 'session not found: SID=I2b45baEdoaOLpOE4J8 NodeID=I2'.

There are a few things i noticed. Always after it didnt work at one time, the next reload it will fully work and when i reload the script a few times a minute it will brake with the above message, also changeing the 'count' parameter to 100 from 99 which should the maximum according to the manual will always fail and make the script brake with the above error message. How is this possible and what can i do to fix this?

The Manual only says that this message occurs when there is no session to be deleted, cause this session was already deleted. But how can that be? I mean i am only closeing the session always at the end of the script and sometimes the session get's closed before so an error occurs stating that session is already closed?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: maybe you should ask this to the SOAP owner?

Answer (score 0):

problem is fixed and for everyone who might as well have the same problem in future here is the solution:

The problem is that the Session ID generated SOMETIMES contain's an @ in the ID string. Thus @ is not automatically escaped by the Soap Class in PHP. You have to manically "escape" it by using:

```
$search_client->__setCookie('SID','"' . $auth_response->return . '"');
```

By using this, the $auth_response->return is completely used as a string and the Soap Class can continue working without any errors. Without doing so the Soap Class would only pass on the Session ID until the @, stoping to use the rest of the Session ID after the @.

Hope this helps somebody.